# QR code scanning and display information in QR code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, qr-code

Is there any sample C# code to scan a QR code and display the information in the QR code.
Do I need any QR code library to do this?

I have VS 2008, Windows CE emulator 3.0, Windows mobile device center.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one. Seems to be compatible with CF

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1C5E731B-4B43-4654-8E9C-7235DD428758

Answer (score 0):

I ported the java based zxing to .net and WinCE. You can get it from here:
http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/
It includes a small example for WinCE.